# How can I include the 0 within the results in this canonical search form?

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, keyup

I have a lottery search form which concatenate six input fields into a single value and returns the results based on the position. My form works correctly for numbers 1-9, but it is unable to display results when I search for 0.

How can I amend my search search to display 0?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#target input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
      $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
    } else if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
      var new_val = $(this).val().substring(1, 2);
      $(this).val(new_val);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_1" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_2" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_2" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_3" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_3" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_4" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_4" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_5" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_5" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_6" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_6" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="search-ticket" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

```
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{'action':'get_numbers', 'n_1':$('#keyword_1').val(), 'n_2':$('#keyword_2').val(), 'n_3':$('#keyword_3').val(), 'n_4':$('#keyword_4').val(), 'n_5':$('#keyword_5').val(), 'n_6':$('#keyword_6').val()},
    function(response){
        $('#datafetch').html(response.data.tickets_data);
        init();
    });
});
});
```